# Function field not getting called from within wizard

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

In openerp v7 I'm trying to add a field to the stock partial picking view wizard, in the list of products. This wizard gets shown when you receive a stock move.

However, my function isn't even getting called, even though the field's string shows up. The logging statement never shows up in the server log. Is this a bug?

```
class stock_partial_picking_line(osv.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "stock.partial.picking.line"

    def _product_description(self, cr, user, ids, name, arg, context=None):

        _logger.info("inside _product_description")

        res = {}
        for line in self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context):
            res[line.id] = line.product_id.x_short_description
        return res

    _columns = {
        'product_description': fields.function(_product_description, string='Description', type='char', method=True),
    }
```

[image: Receive Products Wizard]

Comment: Are you sure that you have added this file reference in the init file ? Coz the code seems fine to me.

Comment: Yeah, it's in there. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: I see it, Can you remove the editable tree view code, and add the details from a simple form interface and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I never figured out why the function wasn't getting called, but I was able to get it working.

It looks like the data is actually passed to the wizard in _partial_move_for, which is inside of stock_partial_picking.py. By overriding it, I was able to normal fields inside of the wizard.

```
def _partial_move_for(self, cr, uid, move):
    partial_move = {
        'product_id' : move.product_id.id,

        # Add product description
        'product_description' : move.name,

        'quantity' : move.product_qty if move.state in ('assigned','draft','confirmed') else 0,
        'product_uom' : move.product_uom.id,
        'prodlot_id' : move.prodlot_id.id,
        'move_id' : move.id,
        'location_id' : move.location_id.id,
        'location_dest_id' : move.location_dest_id.id,
    }
    return partial_move

# Add the product description to the wizard.
# The values get filled in from stock_partial_picking._partial_move_for
class stock_partial_picking_line(osv.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "stock.partial.picking.line"

    _columns = {
        'product_description': fields.char('Description'),
    }
```